# How to create your own security provider with some crypto algorithm?

Tags: java, jce, jca

Using official tutorial i understood the main principles of Java Cryptography Architecture.
But neither the officials nor internet gives me anything distinct about creating my own provider and implementing some crypto algorithms.

I wonder if anyone can give me the source code of a simple security provider and/or a source code of some algorithm, which is used by this provider.

*Overall*, the **main target** is : a ***provider class*** ( simple one, not the complicated like SunJCE ) and a bunch of classes ( or one class ) with ***cryptography algorithm implementation*** ( with all it's doFinal and other method, whatever the implementation class needs )

Comment: Do not invent new crypto algorithms, they are weaker than all algorithms created and reviewed by many cryptographers.

Comment: @Tobias P.: That is like "Don't make new music, all good music has already been written". His new algorithm will probably fail, but there is a chance of 0.0000001% for a success story.

Comment: Look at [bouncycastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) for source code.

Comment: @ott: and with a probability of 99.9999999% his algorithm is totaly weak and easily attackable - like all custom cryptographic algorithms not created by cryptographers. Music is a bad example while it's attractivity depends on personal taste in music but cryptographic algorithms are mathematic problems, so there's no personal choice, only facts.

Comment: The thing is that THIS is my diploma subtask. So that i definetely need this source code. Just to understand how it works

Comment: @Roman Put info like that in your question next time to avoid all this comment spam :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [How to Implement a Provider for the JavaTM Cryptography Extension](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/HowToImplAProvider.html).

Comment: Thank you, i've studied it thoroughly, but it is not enough. I need full source code, not the tiny advices given there. 
And more of it, i need algorithm implementation to understand how exectly i need to impelement other algorithms, to understand how provider understands my algorithm class, how cipher understands it and so on

Comment: Then check out the bouncycastle source as @home suggested in the comments to your question. They have implementations for JCE providers and algorithms :)